# How will I fix this pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pygmt' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pygmt

I have a python code that contains pygmt module/package. I converted this code into an executable file using auto-py-to-exe/pyinstaller. But when you run this executable file, the window console shows this error

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pygmt' distribution was not found and is required by the application

I tried adding --additional-hooks-dir for pygmt but still, the executable file is not working.

Any suggestions that will make it work?